# In GIT, how can I prevent people from changing or removing commits that have already been pushed?

Tags: git, reset, githooks

We recently had an intern run "git reset --hard" and accidentally undo a lot of work on our main GIT repo.  We are in the process of recovering the work, but I want to make sure nothing like this ever happens again.

I know there are a lot of questions about this, but they all seem to be about recovering rather than prevention.  Is there any way I can prevent pushes to our main repo that alter or remove commits that have already been pushed?  Is there a config setting or maybe a push hook that will do the job?

Comment: chmod --recursive 700 /path/to/git/rep  and only allow the administrator do pulls into the main repo.

Comment: A push will never remove commits from the remote repo.  It may move branches around, but the commits are still there.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: a `push -f` may remove commits.

Comment: @Sean: was the intern working directly on the master repo instead of a local clone?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Would that require changing our workflow so that an administrator has to review and pull every commit before it becomes a part of our main repo?

Comment: @larsmans He was working on a local clone.  It could be that I misunderstand what has happened exactly.  We noticed that some changes we made were no longer in the repo and found them as dangling commits.  Our guess was that this was due to the intern doing a reset hard and then pushing.

Comment: @larsmans A push may remote commits from the remote repo, but everyone who has a copy of that repo will still have all the commits, and can just push them back.

Comment: @larsmans Does push -f actually remove the commits, or does it merely make them unreachable?  I would suspect the latter (so they may be removed eventually by git gc, but should remain long enough to be recovered.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 2 [configuration options](http://progit.org/book/ch7-1.html) you can set on your central (bare) repo to help prevent this problem:

```
receive.denyNonFastForwards
receive.denyDeletes
```

The first option requires that all pushes add history only. A `git reset` followed by a `git push` would be denied.

The second closes a loop-hole where someone could delete a remote branch with `git push <origin> :<branch-to-delete>` and then push again with a normal `git push` and whatever changes they wanted.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I'm looking for.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks!